# react-native : how to sort data before screen is drawn?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, react-query

I call data by using `useQuery` and `gql`.

```
const SEE_ALL_FEED_ORDER = gql`
  query seeAllFeedOrder {
    seeAllFeedOrder {
      id
      name
      avatar
      directFeedNumber
    }
  }
`;

  const { data: allFeedData, loading: allFeedDataLoading, 
refetch: allFeedRefetch } = useQuery(SEE_ALL_FEED_ORDER);
```

I named result data as `allFeedData` as above.
And I need to sort this `allFeedData` before screen is shown up.

So I use `useEffect` and `useState`.

```
  const [flatlistdata, setFlatlistdata] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!allFeedDataLoading) {
      setFlatlistdata(
        [...allFeedData.seeAllFeedOrder].sort(function (a, b) {
          return b.directFeedNumber - a.directFeedNumber;
        })
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

So if this query loading is finished, then I put sorted data to `flatlistdata` by using setFlatlistdata.

And with this flatlistdata, I run flatlist.

```
  <FlatList
    data={flatlistdata}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={RankRow}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    onRefresh={refresh}
  />
```

But when I click screen, **undefined is not an object(evaluating 'allFeedData.seeAllFeedOrder'** error comes.

which means I couldn't call allFeedData.
I think this might happen screen is drawn before data is sorted? is that right?

So I also give condition to Flatlist as below.

```
flatlistdata === [] ? (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator size={30}></ActivityIndicator>
    </View>
  ) : 
      <FlatList
        data={flatlistdata}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={RankRow}
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={refresh}
      /> }
```

**or**

```
allFeedDataLoading ? (
    <View>
      <ActivityIndicator size={30}></ActivityIndicator>
    </View>
  ) : 
      <FlatList
        data={flatlistdata}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={RankRow}
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={refresh}
      /> }
```

I intended to draw `ActivityIndicator` screen first before data is sorted and put to flatlistdata and then proper screen show up, but it throws same error.

What is the problem? and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I use useEffect and useState.

why would you need that? the sorted data is *derived* state that doesn't need to be managed separately:

```
const { data: allFeedData } = useQuery(SEE_ALL_FEED_ORDER);

const sortedData = allFeedData ? [...allFeedData.seeAllFeedOrder].sort(...) : []
```

then just pass `sortedData` to the `FlatList`. If it turns out that sorting is slow or that referential identity is important, you can wrap the sorting in `useMemo`. I also have a blog post on this topic: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/dont-over-use-state